# Check and return duplicates array php

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I would like to check if my array has any duplicates and return the duplicated values in an array.
I want this to be as efficient as possible.

Example:

```
$array = array( 1, 2, 2, 4, 5 );
function return_dup($array); // should return 2

$array2 = array( 1, 2, 1, 2, 5 );
function return_dup($array2); // should return an array with 1,2
```

Also the initial array is always 5 positions long

Answer (score 115, accepted):

this will be ~100 times faster than array_diff

```
$dups = array();
foreach(array_count_values($arr) as $val => $c)
    if($c > 1) $dups[] = $val;
```

Comment: Did a very quick benckmark and for me your method is only only coming out twice as fast as JAL's array_diff method, not 100 times faster.

Comment: Pretty sure it does @peter

Comment: Note that `array_count_values` only accepts string and integer values, so if your input array might include other types of values, this is not a good option. But it does work for the example in the question where it looks like the situation is dependably just an array of integers.

Answer (score 42):

You can get the difference of the original array and a copy without duplicates using  [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique) and [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/array_diff_assoc):

```
array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr))
```

Comment: in 2023 this is faster then array_count_values

Answer (score 10):

```
function array_dup($ar){
   return array_unique(array_diff_assoc($ar,array_unique($ar)));
}
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this:

```
function showDups($array)
{
  $array_temp = array();

   foreach($array as $val)
   {
     if (!in_array($val, $array_temp))
     {
       $array_temp[] = $val;
     }
     else
     {
       echo 'duplicate = ' . $val . '<br />';
     }
   }
}


$array = array(1,2,2,4,5);
showDups($array);
```

**Output:**

```
duplicate = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function returndup($array) 
{
    $results = array();
    $duplicates = array();
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if (in_array($item, $results)) {
            $duplicates[] = $item;
        }

        $results[] = $item;
    }

    return $duplicates;
}
```

Comment: Not what the OP asked. They said it should be able to return more than one value.

Comment: Now it returns an array of duplicates. In the first post there was no notice that is needs to return multiple duplicates, so don't blame me!

Comment: Actually, there was:  "if array is array(1,2,1,2,5);
it should return an array with 1,2"

Answer (score 2):

in addition to gumbo's answer:

```
function returndup($arr)
{
  return array_diff_key($arr, array_unique($arr));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests and indeed @user187291's variant is the fastest. But, it turns out that @Gumbo's and @faebser's alternative are almost as fast, @faebser's being just slightly faster than @Gumbo's and sometimes even fastest of all.

Here's the code I used

```
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
$times = 1000000;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++) {
    $dups = array();
    foreach(array_count_values($array) as $val => $c)
        if( $c > 1) $dups[] = $val;
}
$end = microtime(true);

echo 'variant 1 (user187291): ' . ($end - $start);
echo '<br><br><br>';

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++)
    $dups = array_unique(array_diff_assoc($array, array_unique($array)));
$end = microtime(true);

echo 'variant 2 (JAL): ' . ($end - $start);
echo '<br><br><br>';

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++)
    $dups = array_diff_assoc($array, array_unique($array));
$end = microtime(true);

echo 'variant 3 (Gumbo): ' . ($end - $start);
echo '<br><br><br>';

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++)
    $dups = array_diff_key($array, array_unique($array));
$end = microtime(true);

echo 'variant 4 (faebser): ' . ($end - $start);
echo '<br><br><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to return duplicates in an array

```
function printRepeating($arr, $size) 
{ 
    $i; 
    $j; 
    for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) 
        for($j = $i + 1; $j < $size; $j++) 
            if($arr[$i] == $arr[$j]) 
                echo $arr[$i], " "; 
}  



printRepeating($array, sizeof($array,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a solution that will work with an array of arrays (or any array values other than integers or strings) try this:

```
function return_dup( $arr ) {
    $dups = array();
    $temp = $arr;
    foreach ( $arr as $key => $item ) {
        unset( $temp[$key] );
        if ( in_array( $item, $temp ) ) {
            $dups[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $dups;
}


$arr = array(
    array(
        0 => 'A',
        1 => 'B',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'A',
        1 => 'B',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'C',
        1 => 'D',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'C',
        1 => 'D',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'E',
        1 => 'F',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'F',
        1 => 'E',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'Y',
        1 => 'Z',
    ),
);

var_export( return_dup( $arr ) );
/*
array (
    0 => array (
        0 => 'A',
        1 => 'B',
    ),
    1 => array (
        0 => 'C',
        1 => 'D',
    ),
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem if you have duplicate values then you have to return those values. I write a function for this problem. If your array has duplicate values this function returns these values within the array otherwise it returns null values. Here is an example:

```
function containsDuplicate($array_values) {
    $duplicates_values = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array_values); $i++){
        for ($j=$i+1; $j <count($array_values) ; $j++) { 
            if ($array_values[$i] == $array_values[$j]) {
                $duplicates_values[] =  $array_values[$i];
            }
        }
    
    }
    if(count($duplicates_values) > 0){
        return $duplicates_values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much time complexity.  Other answers are more direct, more elegant.  `count()` should not be called on every iteration.  `if(count($duplicates_values) > 0){` can be `if ($duplicates_values) {`, but then why would anyone want to write a function that has a conditional `return`.

Answer (score -3):

$duplicate_array = array();

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){

    for($j=0;$j<count($array);$j++){

      if($i != $j && $array[$i] == $array[$j]){

        if(!in_array($array[$j], $duplicate_array)){

          $duplicate_array[] = $array[$j];

        }

      }

    }    

  }
```

Comment: At O(n^3), that's definitely the slowest approach.

Comment: O(n^4) actually. in_array() method works like a loop.