# Counting duplicate entries in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I need to find and count duplicate values after post the array

```
foreach ($_POST["marks"] as $marks => $value) {

need to display duplicate values and their count here

}
```

please help

Comment: Duplicate there are many questions asked in stackoverflow itself regarding this.
[Stack overflow display only duplicate elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259407/php-return-only-duplicated-entries-from-an-array)

Comment: but reason is I need to count duplicate values inside the foreach loop,,,Please give me solution for above code

Comment: In the link i gave check the answer given by bucabay and shiva

Comment: [try this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450022/check-and-return-duplicates-array-php)

Answer (score -1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

output

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```