# Find duplicate values in array and save them in a separate array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

Bit of a strange one, so I am looking to get all duplicates in an array, and save each of them in a separate array. It's a bit difficult to explain so I will try with an example.

```
$array = array('apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'banana');
```

I am looking to find all duplicates (in this instance, apples and oranges) and save each in their own separate array, which will then be counted afterwards to find out how many of each duplicate exists in each of the arrays.

Once I have counted them, I will then run a mysqli query dependant on the amount found (there can only be a maximum of 6 of the same item).

An example ideal output would be

```
$array1 to be ('apple', 'apple', 'apple'), $array2 to be ('orange', 'orange') and $array3 would be ('banana')
```

I apologise in advance if this question doesn't make much sense, but it's pretty difficult for me to explain.

Comment: Its pretty simple logic what have you tried? Need hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450022/check-and-return-duplicates-array-php

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I did see that post prior to posting my own question, but that doesn't appear to solve my problem. I am not looking to count the values, I am looking to essentially split the array into various arrays, each of the new "split" arrays containing each of the duplicates (as explained in my example output). Do you think there is any way this could be possible please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = [];
$array = ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'orange', 'orange'];

foreach ($array as $a) {
    $count[$a]++;
}

print_r($count);
```

Output ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XfnEb)):

```
Warning: Undefined array key "apple" in /in/XfnEb on line 7

Warning: Undefined array key "banana" in /in/XfnEb on line 7

Warning: Undefined array key "orange" in /in/XfnEb on line 7
Array
(
    [apple] => 3
    [banana] => 2
    [orange] => 2
)
```

You could then loop through the one array with key => value obtaining the 'fruit' and occurrence.

Edit: You'll need to uppercase/lowercase the key if you're case-insensitive searching.

Comment: This does appear that it could work. Would this also be viable if the "fruit" in question wasn't known? So let's say there were kiwi's in the list too, and some tomatoes, but neither of which were chosen, would I still need to loop through those to check if there were any occurrences in the array? Sorry for the questions, I'm (clearly) terrible with arrays

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) functions

```
$array = array('apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'banana');

// counts all the values
$count = array_count_values($array);

// result array
$result = array();

// Loop and push new array filled with values times count
foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = array_fill(0, $value, $key);
}

// Print result
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```