# Split an array into multiple arrays depending on number of similar adjacent values

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array containing multiple values like this

```php
$input_array = array('45', '21', '45', '45', '45', '29', '35', '35', '21');
```

Now I want to split it into multiple arrays to group adjacent values if they are similar.
For Example, the above array should split into 6 different arrays

```php
$input_array_1 = array('45');

$input_array_2 = array('21');

$input_array_3 = array('45', '45', '45');

$input_array_4 = array('29');

$input_array_5 = array('35', '35');

$input_array_6 = array('21');
```

is this something possible in PHP?

Comment: *is this something possible in PHP?* - fortunately yes it is.  Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried using array_chunk() function but I have no idea how can I dynamically change its 'size' parameter and run the function again every time. I googled for an answer but did not find anything which can help me solve this issue

Comment: write the code you tried to solve your problem and we can help you

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/47402882/296555

Comment: @waterloomatt That doesn't handle the adjacent aspect of this problem, does it? I mean, wouldn't it group all the 45s together in the above example?

Comment: It would. My bad.

Comment: Related process/topic: [How to count the consecutive duplicate values in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5255281/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend the use of dynamic number of resulting vars like you asked in your question. It's better to have the result inside an array. This way you can cycle through the array indexes, instead of guessing how many $input_array_(number) your code generated.

```
$input_array = array('45', '21', '45', '45', '45', '29', '35', '35', '21');

$result = [];
$index = 0;
$processedElement = null;
foreach ($input_array as $currentElement) { 
    if ($processedElement != $currentElement) {
        $index++;   
    }
    $result[$index][] = $currentElement;
    $processedElement = $currentElement;
}
```

Printing `$result` will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => 45
            [2] => 45
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 29
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 35
            [1] => 35
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input_array = array('45', '21', '45', '45', '45', '29', '35', '35', '21');

$arr=array();
$prev_value=null;
foreach ($input_array as $key => $value) {
    if($value==$prev_value){
       array_push($arr[count($arr)-1],$value); 
    }
    else{
        $prev_value=$value;
        array_push($arr,array($value));
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `foreach` to loop though, then check the last value in the new array and append, to get the global vars, create an array first then extract, as shown below.

```
<?php
$input_array = array('45', '21', '45', '45', '45', '29', '35', '35', '21');

$result = [];

foreach ($input_array as $key => $value) {
    // get last item in array
    $last = end($result);

    // does last == this one
    if (isset($last[0]) && $last[0] === $value) {
        // append it
        $result['input_array_'.count($result)][] = $value;
    } else {
        // create new
        $result['input_array_'.(count($result)+1)][] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($result);

// to conform to question (not required)
extract($result);
print_r($input_array_3);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [input_array_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
        )

    [input_array_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
        )

    [input_array_3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => 45
            [2] => 45
        )

    [input_array_4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 29
        )

    [input_array_5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 35
            [1] => 35
        )

    [input_array_6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => 45
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 45
)
```

https://3v4l.org/RHsY4

Answer (score 0):

You can try. Hope it helps you

```
$input_array = array('45', '21', '45', '45', '45', '29', '35', '35', '20');

$allChunk = [];
$Chunk = [];
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($input_array as $value) {
    $chunk[] = $value;
    if(in_array(next($input_array),$chunk)) {
        continue;
    }
    $allChunk[] = $chunk;
    unset($chunk);
}
var_dump($allChunk);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method builds up a list of similar values, then when the value changes it adds this list to the end of the output array.  The only thing is the first time in it has an empty list, rather than exclude adding it, I use `array_shift()` to remove this blank entry at the end...

```
$input_array = array('45', '21', '45', '45', '45', '29', '35', '35', '21');
$output = [];
$temp = [];
foreach ( $input_array as $value )  {
    if ( $value != ($temp[0]??'') ){
        $output[] = $temp;
        $temp = [$value];
    }
    else    {
        $temp[] = $value;
    }
}
array_shift($output);
$output[] = $temp;
print_r($output);
```

gives the output (truncated)...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => 45
            [2] => 45
        )
...
```