# Algorithm to find list of most duplicated based on N

Tags: php, algorithm, duplicates

Given a function with parameters (array, mostRepeatedN), the function should return array of most repeated numbers based on the variable mostRepeatedN

Example:

```
 Array(7, 5, 5, 8, 6, 5, 7, 4, 7, 4, 5), mostRepeatedN = 2
```

In this case the function will return the 2 most repeated number `[5, 7]` because 5 is the most repeated and 7 is the second most repeated, if `mostRepeatedN = 3` then the function will return `[5, 7, 4]`

Note that the returned array must be sorted from the top most repeated, if we sort the array after we find the duplicates, the answer will not be O(N).

Can this be done `O(N)`? What is the most efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Look at the PHP Manual for [PHP Array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) There is one in there that will do almost all of it for you at almost zero effort from you

Comment: you can use hash to find it.

Comment: Here is a SO Q&A  that you could have searched for and found quicker than asking a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450022/check-and-return-duplicates-array-php

Comment: @AtulKumar Can you provide example on using hash to solve this problem using O(N)?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It doesn't matter the language here, I'm looking for the most effiecent way to solve this problem.

Comment: But you put a PHP tag on the question. So you aer going to get PHP based answers

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have researched already, most of those questions is answering ANOTHER question (how to find duplicate) the issue here is not only finding duplicates, it's find the most duplicated based on N), I doubt that you read the question correctly.

Comment: @RiggsFolly There is no need to give attitude here, if you don't like what you are reading you don't have to help.

Comment: I dont like, but I am still helping

Comment: @RiggsFolly Great, the issue here is "sorting" basically I can use hash to record duplicates but it will be unsorted, if I sort it the function won't be O(N)

Comment: [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) is O(n) and then going through that array is also O(N) so O(N) + O(N) = O(N)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly speaking there are many ways to do it what you want to achieve but not very sure the way I am doing it is the most efficient or not?. If I were you then I'll try this way to get my job done.

- Find the duplicate element `counts` using [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).
- Sort it on ascending order using [asort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).
- Get only the first `n` elements with top duplicate value using
  [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

  ```
  <?php
     function mostRepeated($array=[],$mostRepeatedN=1){
      $totals = array_count_values($array);
      arsort( $totals );
      return array_keys(array_slice($totals, 0, $mostRepeatedN,true));
     }

  $array =[7, 5, 5, 8, 6, 5, 7, 4, 7, 4, 5];
  $mostRepeatedN = 3;
  $result = mostRepeated($array,$mostRepeatedN);
  print '<pre>';
  print_r($result);
  print '</pre>';
  ?>
  ```

**SEE DEMO** https://eval.in/1040197

Comment: Hi @Being Sunny

I gave similar answer to the interviewer but I he didn't like it, he was looking for O(N) answer.